# facebook app redirects forever on authentication

Tags: authentication, facebook

I have the following code in my appinclude.php file and for some reason the app keeps redirecting forever and firefox gives me an error that the redirect will never end.

I am not sure if i am missing something but i have tried to change the redirect_uri to the directory on my server where the app is hosted but i get an error from facebook and i have also tried `https://apps.facebook.com/gamesorbiter/` but that didnt work :(

I am totally lost, any help is appreciated.

```
$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
$user = $facebook->require_login();
$facebook->redirect('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=132611566776827&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/gamesorbiter/&scope=publish_stream');
```